# Rails - Passing a variable while using Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When creating a new model object using simple form, I need to pass the id of one object to the new object as it relies on the id for its URL. The routing is:

```
resources :coins do
  resources :questions
end
```

I am attempting to do this using a hidden field tag but its not working. The ID is not passed and as a result, the new object does not save.

```
<%= simple_form_for @question, url: coin_questions_path(@coin.id) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :ques_num %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:coin_id, @coin.id) %>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Prior to this, I was using collection_select in simple form to manually enter the ID and it worked, however I need it to happen automatically. Is there a better way of doing this that will do what I am looking for?

Question model:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :find_coin
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @questions = Question.where(coin_id: @coin.id).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @coin
    @question = current_user.questions.build
  end

    def create
      @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
      if @question.save
        redirect_to coin_question_path(@coin.id, @question.id)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

  .
  .
  .

  private

    def find_question
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_coin
      @coin = Coin.find(params[:coin_id])
    end

    def question_params
        params.require(:question).permit(:content, :ques_num, :coin_id)
    end

end
```

Comment: Right now you're finding the `@coin` before all your actions. I don't think that's necessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use `hidden_field` with a value - [read more](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field)

For example:

`<%= f.hidden_field :coin_id, value: @coin.id %>`

And then the value will be in the `params[:question][:coin_id]` on create, so the rest should work as it is now. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<%= hidden_field_tag(:coin_id, @coin.id) %>` will generate a field with a name of just "coin_id"; you want "question[coin_id]"

You should, in turn, assign this value to the object in your controller. `@question.coin_id = @coin.id`, or `@question = Question.new(:user => current_user, :coin => @coin)` or `@question = current_user.questions.new(:coin => @coin)`

`<%= f.input :coin_id, :as => :hidden %>`

Comment: The input is missing the `@coin.id`.